# Is it possible to get daily insights for instagram-graph-api?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

Is there a way to get daily insights (likes, comments) on instagram posts via the graph API? I only get the aggregated values per post as a lifetime value. Is there a way (other than getting the data daily and computing it yourself) to get daily engagement data on the posts e.g. using "since"/"until"? It seems like it is not possible on a post level, but maybe on a page level? For facebook I was able to get it for the feed using the since parameter:

```
id/feed?fields=comments.limit(1).summary(true),likes.limit(1).summary(true)&since=1564610400
```

Maybe there is a similar way?